# Airflow PythonBranchOperator returns invalid value

Tags: python, airflow

I'm having issues with Airflow 1.10 Python Branch operator. I have a dag that scans a cloud bucket, and processes files if found. If the file is missing it hits the no_file_found dummy operator and completes, otherwise it moves forward to some parsing steps.

With a single file this workflow works great. My issue arises when I add the same logic for a second file. Currently the check_for_Post_Performance returns cleans_headers_for_gcm task and I'm at a total loss how that happens. From the outline below it should have only two paths forward, clean_headers_Post_Perfromance or no_file_found.

[image: Graph View of Workflow]

I create these tasks dynamically from a list of file names. I loop through each filename and build the following operators:

```
def build_check(filename):
    return BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id=f'check_for_{file_name}'.replace(' ', '_'),
        python_callable=check_file_exists,
        op_kwargs={'filename': filename},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
   )

def check_file_exists(filename, **context):
    xcom_value = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'list_files')
    if any(filename in s for s in xcom_value):
        return f'clean_headers_for_{file_name}'.replace(' ', '_')   
    else:
        return 'no_file_found'
```

I've checked the rendered task template to confirm 'Post Performance' is passed for the filename variable
[image: Airflow Post Performance Rendered Template]

but when looking at the logs I see the following:

```
[2021-12-02 20:15:56,742] {logging_mixin.py:120} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: example_dag.check_for_Post_Performance 2021-12-02T20:14:50.724084+00:00 [running]> on host 21d0393eb686
[2021-12-02 20:15:56,766] {python_operator.py:114} INFO - Done. Returned value was: clean_headers_for_GCM
[2021-12-02 20:15:56,767] {skipmixin.py:122} INFO - Following branch clean_headers_for_GCM
[2021-12-02 20:15:56,773] {skipmixin.py:158} INFO - Skipping tasks ['no_file_found', 'clean_headers_for_Post_Performance']
```

My best guess is the function isn't created each loop like I think it is, or some trigger rule is tripping me up. How can I have each file in my source list either reach no_file_found or clean_headers task independently of each other?

**EDIT**
Here is the code I use to build the tasks from a static list:

```
for file_name, table_name in FILES().items():
    import_to_bq = import_file(file_name, table_name)
    clean_headers_task =  clean_headers(file_name)

    start_import >> list_files >> build_check(file_name) >> [clean_headers_task, no_file] 
    clean_headers_task >> import_to_bq >> archive_file(file_name)
```

Comment: You can't create tasks at runtime. Tasks are created when code/DAG is parsed and there is no context at that time, including on what `list_files` would render. Are there only 2 files that could be listed ? If more, consider creating one task that handles multiple files in a `for` loop in a `PythonOperator`. Also, your snippet is incomplete - how would/is `build_check` called. Posting a complete code would get more traction.

Comment: I use a dictionary that I populate with any files I'd like to grab with this dag. ListFiles uses GoogleCloudStorageListOperator which will list all files in a bucket and tosses them into xcom. I then parse this xcom for matches. The answer below set me on the right track but thanks for the clarifying questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's the difference between `file_name` and `filename`? Looks like the task IDs use `file_name` while the arg is `filename`. Should these functions both use `filename`?

```py
def build_check(filename):
    return BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id=f'check_for_{filename}'.replace(' ', '_'),
        python_callable=check_file_exists,
        op_kwargs={'filename': filename},
        provide_context=True,
        dag=dag
   )

def check_file_exists(filename, **context):
    xcom_value = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids=f'list_files')
    if any(filename in s for s in xcom_value):
        return f'clean_headers_for_{filename}'.replace(' ', '_')   
    else:
        return 'no_file_found'
```

Comment: Don't think that's the issue but OP's code would indeed fail as-is as `file_name` is not defined.

Comment: Nice catch. I went through and fixed all the variations of FileName vs File_name... and it worked. I've updated my original post with my loop but this at least set me on the right track even if I'm still not 100% of the root of the issue. Thanks!